# Node Enlistment for the Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu Openstack

Tags: networking, maas, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

After following the Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu Openstack Guide and the more indepth installation guide, I have single functioning node which is both my region controller and a cluster controller (I will refer to this node as the 'controller').

I have configured my network such that I have an additional node connected to this cluster's secondary NIC (I will refer to this node as 'node'). My controller can ping the Internet and node. My node can ping the controller.

So now I am trying to enlist and commission this node to be apart of this cluster. The node is configured to boot from the network; thus, MAAS should recognize it and it should recognize MAAS. However, the MAAS UI never recognizes any available nodes.

I manually entered the information to add this node. It has been labeled as "commissioning," but there is a yellow circle to the left of the FQDN. Hovering the mouse over this circle presents the label "unknown." Through the node's MAC address, MAAS can recognize which network interface the node is on.

I cannot figure out why this node is not automatically being enlisted and why the state of this manually entered node is unknown.

Has anyone had this issue before? If so, how can I resolve this?

---

Edit:

Previously my system image was listed as synced, but now it is "out-of-sync." I tried updating the image upload and giving it time to sync, but nothing has changed.

---

Per request, the following links will take you to the files for [/var/log/maas/maas.log](http://stadther.net/resources/maas.log) and [/var/log/maas/pserv.log](http://stadther.net/resources/pserv.log). These files are extremely long and contain warnings and errors.

Comment: Do you have another dhcp/dns service listening on that network? If so the network boot could be attempting to pxe from that rather than the maas provided dns/dhcp

Comment: Can MAAS turn the node on and off? In other words, have you configured the power aspect correctly?

But even without that, if you boot the node up manually, and with pxe boot selected first, it should boot off MAAS, and MAAS should list it.

So what happens when you turn the node on manually and have it PXE boot?

Comment: @gangstaluv, I do not have another dhcp/dns service running on that network. My region/cluster controller is set to have a static ip address on its network (the one from which it receives internet). The additional network which it connects (via secondary NIC) is managed by MAAS's dhcp/dns.

Comment: @andreas, MAAS cannot turn the node on or off. I manually configured the node in MAAS and set its power aspect as "Wake on Lan." This setting is also configured in the BIOS of the node in addition to boot to network. Even when I boot the node manually, it is not auto detected by MAAS.

Comment: Can you paste.ubuntu.com the /var/log/maas/maas.log and /var/log/maas/pserv.log preferably around the time that you attempt to have the node detected by MAAS. If pserv is not indicating that its actually attempting to communicate with that node then that usually means something with the network is misconfigured. At the very least it should PXE from the MAAS server. Also maybe a `sosreport -o maas` would help here as well.

Comment: @gangstaluv, I have included links to those files in the edited question.

Comment: Its giving you a bunch of connection timeouts which indicate a problem with the network setup.

Comment: @gangstaluv, so the issue is with my network topology?